# ¿Cómo le digo a GCC que no haga stack alignment?

Tags: c, gcc, asm

Tengo mi función con la que empieza el programa compilado en y para Linux en amd64:

```
0000000000403060 <_start>:
403060:       50                      push   %rax
403061:       58                      pop    %rax
403062:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp  <----INSTRUCCIÓN QUE NO QUIERO
403066:       48 8b 74 24 08          mov    0x8(%rsp),%rsi
40306b:       48 8d 3d 4e 12 00 00    lea    0x124e(%rip),%rdi   # 4042c0 <pow10.0+0x100>                       
403072:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
403074:       e8 87 f9 ff ff          call   402a00 <printf>
403079:       31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
40307b:       e8 10 fe ff ff          call   402e90 <exit>
```

¿Cómo le digo a gcc que el stack ya esta alineado a 16 bytes y que no debe emitir la instrucción marcada con la flecha?

Comment: Si declaras alguna variable, es probable que se deba a eso. Ya que la forma que el stack crece negativamente. ¿Puedes incluir el código en la respuesta?

Comment: @Mateo Efectivamente es eso. Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha solucionado la duda perfectamente.